# without [someone] choosing [something]

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases

could you tell me if there is a mistake in this sentence:

> "Thus, the colors of his numbers became, without his choosing it, the
>   colors of events..[]"

I'm confused about the **his** choosing it. I feel like it would be more appropriate to use **him** instead.
If my feeling is wrong could you point me at a source where I could find more examples like this or some relative grammar materials (dictionaries or ESL sources would do too). 
Thanks!

Comment: Search for “possessive with the gerund” in the search box. Either his or him is okay. Or recast: although he did not choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine. The possessive (his) is a bit more formal.